# How to put fetch data in a variable

Tags: javascript, json, variables, fetch, put

I have a code that results `undefined` whenever I try fetch results into a variable

```
var data;
fetch('./js/samplejson.json')
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then(output => {
        var data = output;
    } 
)
console.log(data);
```

How can I get a result of

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

inside data variable

Comment: @MichaelGeary yup.thats true.he is declared the data at the top.like [1,2,3] earlier

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `fetch()` call is *asynchronous*. It returns before the data comes back from the server. When you try to access the data after the call, you're trying to access it before the server has responded.

You need to handle that data *inside* the callback, or in a function called from that callback. In other words, where you do `var data = output;`, don't do that. It won't help to remove the `var` so the code sets the global `data` variable as suggested in a comment. The problem isn't scope, it's timing. Process the `output` data right there inside the callback, or call another function and pass `output` to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can get data from log here.

```
fetch('./js/samplejson.json')
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then(output => {
        var data = output;
        console.log(data);
    } 
)
```